# DBLib error driving me crazy

Tags: database, perl

I am working on a perl script that has multiple database calls and I continuously get the following error:

DB-Library error:
        Attempt to initiate a new SQL Server operation with results pending.

In my code I have the following:

The first call to the database performs a number of insert statements built from a hash:

```
while (my ($key, $value) = each(%holidays)) {

    system("log4k", "DEBUG", "$0", "Staging holiday info data for: $cal_name: $key");

    $sql = "INSERT INTO stg_holiday_data (hol_mnemonic, hol_date, hol_comment, dml_type)    VALUES (\"$cal_name\", $key, \"$value\", \"N\")";
    system("log4k", "TRACE", "$0", "SQL being executed: $sql");

    if ($test == 0) {

        $dbh->dbcmd($sql);

        ($dbh->dbsqlexec() && $dbh->dbresults)
            or &fatalError("Database error in $sql", "DB_ERROR");

        while($dbh->dbresults != NO_MORE_RESULTS) {

            while(my @dat = $dbh->dbnextrow){}
        }
    }
}
```

immediately after that finishes I close off the connection, and cancel it to make sure that there are no results left to be processed by issuing:

```
$dbh->dbcancel();
$dbh->dbclose();
```

From there I call a separate subroutine to execute a stored procedure which will produce three lines of output signifying row numbers:

subroutine call

```
&run_sproc() if ($test == 0);
```

subroutine:

```
sub run_sproc() {

    system("log4k", "DEBUG", "$0", "Loading staged holiday data");

    my $sql1 = "upd_holiday_data";
    system("log4k", "TRACE", "$0", "SQL being executed: $sql1");

    my($dbh2) = new Sybase::DBlib $ENV{DATABASE_USER}, $ENV{DATABASE_PASSWORD}, $ENV{DATABASE_SERVER}, "GME_calendar_sync";
    &fatalError("Failed to login imagine database", "DB_LOGIN_ERROR") unless ($dbh2);

    $dbh2->dbcmd($sql1);
    ($dbh2->dbsqlexec() && $dbh2->dbresults ) 
        or &fatalError ("Database error in $sql", "DB_ERROR");

    while ($dbh2->dbresults != NO_MORE_RESULTS) {

        while (my @d = $dbh2->dbnextrow) {

            system("log4k", "TRACE", "$0", "Next row being inserted @d");
        }
    }
    $dbh2->dbclose();
}
```

I do have a third SQL block that comes after the stored procedure that works fine with or without this subroutine.

What is happening is I am receiving the error mentioned above right before the results from the stored procedure print.  I have tried everything I can imagine to make sure that all the results are being processed.  A sample of the log output is below:

```
[Tuesday, 23 October 2012 13:30:02 BST] [DEBUG] gme_process_calendars.pl: Staging holiday info data for: CA: 20251226
[Tuesday, 23 October 2012 13:30:03 BST] [TRACE] gme_process_calendars.pl: SQL being executed: INSERT INTO stg_holiday_data (hol_mnemonic, hol_date, hol_comment, dml_type)    VALUES ("CA", 20251226, "upload", "N")
[Tuesday, 23 October 2012 13:30:03 BST] [DEBUG] gme_process_calendars.pl: Staging holiday info data for: CA: 20220103
[Tuesday, 23 October 2012 13:30:03 BST] [TRACE] gme_process_calendars.pl: SQL being executed: INSERT INTO stg_holiday_data (hol_mnemonic, hol_date, hol_comment, dml_type) VALUES ("CA", 20220103, "upload", "N")
[Tuesday, 23 October 2012 13:30:03 BST] [DEBUG] gme_process_calendars.pl: Loading staged holiday data
[Tuesday, 23 October 2012 13:30:03 BST] [TRACE] gme_process_calendars.pl: SQL being executed: upd_holiday_data
DB-Library error:
    Attempt to initiate a new SQL Server operation with results pending.
[Tuesday, 23 October 2012 13:30:03 BST] [TRACE] gme_process_calendars.pl: Next row being inserted 310107230
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated as I have already tried everything I can find doing an internet search and reading the documentation.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe you should do something like this:
    $dbh->dbcmd("exec $sql1");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution Found:

In the run_sproc sub routine, the check:

```
 ($dbh2->dbsqlexec() && $dbh2->dbresults ) 
        or &fatalError ("Database error in $sql", "DB_ERROR");
```

the second condition $dbh2->dbresults is what is causing this error condition,  once this was removed the error did not come up anymore.

Comment: that command *Retrieves result information from the dataserver after having executed `dbsqlexec()`*. I think you should check the return value of `dbsqlexec()` `$status = $dbh2->dbsqlexec()` and see what the value of `$status` is

Comment: Thanks Tudor, after removing the `$dbh2->dbresults` from the line above that is essentially what i am doing with the resultant command doing:

    `$dbh2_dbsqlexec() or &fatalError ("Database error in $sql", "DB_ERROR"); `

it just saves me from specifically writing another test on status

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that your `run_proc` method tries to execute this SQL:

```
my $sql1 = "upd_holiday_data";
```

which I doubt is a valid SQL command

Comment: This is a valid command as you can see in the sample log output that it is producing results, i have used exec, execute as well and received the same results

Comment: its also worth mentioning that no matter what query is in the "$sql1" var I get the DB-Lib error